# php for each input to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have currently 5 input name box which i want to insert into mysql database.
Here is my code with basic knowledge of php i have, but know there would be any better way of code as i am just a noob.

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name2" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name3" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name4" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name5" value="" />
</form>
```

on result.php i am using this mysql code

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name1, name2, name3. name4, name5) 
VALUES ('$_POST["name1"]',  '$_POST["name2"]', '$_POST["name3"]', 
'$_POST["name4"]', '$_POST["name5"]'");
```

Suppose if there are 1000 fields how do i manage it ?

Comment: Sanitize your inputs, before inserting them into the database or else you will be subject to all kinds of SQL injections! Besides your code wont work, as the `"` are mixed up.

Comment: I hope this is not a website available over public www ...

Comment: How is your table setup? It looks like now its inserting everything in the same row.

Comment: quotes inside quotes need escaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i am using this mysql code

The code you've posted should be failing and generating errors - but you've made no mentioned of these. Is it failing? Or is this *not* the code you are using?

(you've tried to embed double quotes without escaping them, associative indexes inside double quotes should not have additional quotes around them, you've used a period as a field seperator).

> Suppose if there are 1000 fields how do i manage it ?

Normalise your database.

Answer (score 1):

You have huge typos and aren't using any escapes. If you want to have 1000 fields, how do you expect the user to type every single name seperately?